# What would be the most maintainable solution to define tables that have many columns in common?

Tags: postgresql, database-schema

I have the following schema (which is one approach):

```
CONTACTS
--------
|id    |
|name  |--------------------------
--------        \                 \
|                \                 \
|                 \                 \
^                  ^                 ^
PHONE_NUMBERS    ADDRESSES        EMAILS    
--------------   --------------   --------------
|id          |   |id          |   |id          |
|FK(contacts)|   |FK(contacts)|   |FK(contacts)|
|preferred   |   |preferred   |   |preferred   |
|type        |   |type        |   |type        |
|inserted_at |   |inserted_at |   |inserted_at |
| ---------- |   | ---------- |   | ---------- |
|phone_no    |   |address     |   |email       |   
--------------   |city        |   --------------
                 |(...)       |
```

The other two solution I came up with was (1) [inheritence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/tutorial-inheritance.html) and (2) dumping all of them in one table which is probably the ugliest. (Or maybe I am doing something fundamentally wrong.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the right approach when designing OLTP systems. Please remember, that having multiple tables in your database don't make reading from them slower and is called database normalisation.

It's better to have a dictionary table contacts and manage them within one table and add references to it using foreign keys in different tables implementing 1:N relationships between entities.

You could dig deeper into normalisation and also create a table for lookup on your type column for each table to avoid data redundancy.

You could think of table inheritance but try to model it the way your business realities are represented. Avoid second approach which is "the ugliest" as you've already noticed.

Inheritance might not be what you're looking for - inspect FROM ONLY clause. You still have different types per entity.